# emscripten: How can I solve UnboundTypeError

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

I am trying to build with emscripten a program which uses std::vector and std::map and the compilation is successful.
However, when I ran it on the web browser(firefox/chrome), UnboundTypeError was catched.

> [03:21:26.453] UnboundTypeError: Cannot call intArrayToVector due to
>   unbound types: Pi

Here is c++ code and HTML file which uses generated javascript code.

test.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>

using namespace emscripten;

std::vector<int> intArrayToVector(int* input, int num){
    std::vector<int> vec;
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
        int val = *(input+i);
        vec.push_back(val);
    }
    return vec;
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(test){
    register_vector<int>("VectorInt");
    function("intArrayToVector", &intArrayToVector, allow_raw_pointer<arg<0>>());
}
```

test.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="test.js"></script>
<script>
    var num = 6;
    var buf = Module._malloc(100);
    var arr = new Int8Array(num);
    for(var i=0; i<num; i++){
        arr[i] = i+2;
    }
    Module.HEAP8.set(arr, buf);
    var v = Module.intArrayToVector(buf, num);

    for(var i=0; i<num; i++){
        console.log(v.get(i));
    }
    Module._free(buf);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript code was generated by the command below:

> $ em++ --bind test.cpp -o test.js

How can I solve this problem? 
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Int8Array() creates 8 bits integers?

Comment: yes,it's an array of 8-bit integers

Comment: I don't know how emscripten handle it: your default C++ integer size is bigger than 8bits. `short int` is at least 16bits...

Comment: I tried with Int32Array() and HEAP32, but I've got the same result...

Answer (score 10):

[Embind doesn't support pointers to primitive types.](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/612#issuecomment-18428394)  "Pi" means to "pointer to integer."

If you will always know the size of the array in advance, you could try passing the array as a const reference.  e.g.

```
std::vector<int> intArrayToVector(const int (&input)[100])
```

Or you can cheat and use an integer parameter for the pointer and use `reinterpret_cast` to treat it as a pointer.  e.g.

```
std::vector<int> intArrayToVector(uintptr_t input, size_t len) {
    const int* ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(input);
    ....
}
```

Or you can use [the `cwrap` API](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-ccall-cwrap) which does support pointers to primitive types.