# Objects with primitive data pointers and emscripten

Tags: c++, pointers, emscripten

**Rephrasing the question:**

How should I bind a function that returns an object with an array as member variable from a C/C++ API to javascript when I don't know the length of the array a priori?

---

I have a struct with a primitive data type pointer

```
struct Person
{
    const char* name;
    int age;
    Person()
    {}
};
```

and I have a function that should return this an object of this struct

```
Person getPerson()
{
    Person p = Person();
    p.name = "Philipp";
    p.age = 77;
    return p;
}
```

and following embindings:

```
EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS() {
    value_object<Person>("Person")
        .field("age", &Person::age)
        .field("name", &Person::name)
        ;

    function("getPerson", &getPerson);
}
```

This doesn't work and the compiler also tells me `static_assert failed "Implicitly binding raw pointers is illegal. Specify allow_raw_pointer<arg<?>>"`
I tried to understand [API documentation](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/bind.h.html#policies) but I couldn't make it work. E.g. I tried to add `allow_raw_pointer()` (and variants of this) to the `.field` of `name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`class_::property` can specify getter and setter function.

```
    std::string getPersonName(const Person& p) {
        return p.name;
    }

    EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS() {
        class_<Person>("Person")
            .property("age", &Person::age)
            .property("name", &getPersonName)
            ;

        function("getPerson", &getPerson);
    }
    /*
      var p = Module.getPerson();
      console.log(p);
      console.log(p.age);
      console.log(p.name);
    */
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, before I accept I'm wondering if it is possible to avoid using std::string and return const char* in the getter.

Comment: As far as I know, some thing like `(...).function("namePtr", &getPersonNamePtr, allow_raw_pointers())` can be compiled, but it causes runtime error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355880/emscripten-how-can-i-solve-unboundtypeerror