# how to expose a C++ function with raw pointer input to javascript via emscripten

Tags: webassembly, emscripten

I have this C++ code that I'm exposing to JS as a WASM module using emscripten. My goal is to expose a function `f` that takes a raw pointer (`float* x`) as input. I have two versions: a C++ version (`MyClass::f`) and a C version (`f`) that do the same, but the C++ version doesn't work, I suspect there's some binding code I'm missing but I haven't figured it out:

```cpp
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>

class MyClass {
public:
    static int f(float* x) {
        return 1;
    }
};

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(lib) {
    emscripten::class_<MyClass>("MyClass")
        .class_function("f", &MyClass::f, emscripten::allow_raw_pointers());
}

extern "C" int EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE f(float* x) {
    return 1;
}
```

The C version works, even if I just call it with a regular int in the JS console in the browser.

```
_f(3)
# returns 1
```

But the C++ version fails with an error due to some missing binding code (I guess `Pf` refers to pointer to float):

```
Module.MyClass.f(3)
```

This results in:

```
UnboundTypeError: Cannot call MyClass.f due to unbound types: Pf
```

I know that I shouldn't be passing `3` as input, but this is just to keep the example simple. The error in the C++ version is not related to that, but rather to some missing binding code apparently. What's missing in the C++ code to make this work?

Comment: what is your compile command and your JS code? Could it be a name clash because you use `f` both for C++ and for C. Perhaps try renaming one of the two functions

Comment: Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355880/emscripten-how-can-i-solve-unboundtypeerror